# Fitnesse and dbFit: how to escape colons in SQL queries

Tags: testing, fitnesse, dbfit

I've a problem with escaping colons and dashes in SQL queries when I use dbFit with Fitnesse.

Such statement doesn't work:

```
!|Query|select to_char(my_birthday,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SI') from family|
```

I need to replace colons and dashes with some other acceptable characters, ex.

```
!|Query|select to_char(my_birthday,'YYYY_MM_DD HH24_MI_SI') from family|
```

Do you know how to solve it properly without using the 2nd approach ?

Cheers,
foxrafi

Comment: Are you using the FitSharp or the Java version of DbFit? When you say "such statement doesn't work", what error are you seeing?

Comment: It turned out the problem is only with colons. When I use a colon in a SQL query I receive such error:
 
Standard Error:

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)

Comment: A sample query that doesn't work looks like that: !|Query|select to_char(current_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI_SS') t from dual|

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you need. From http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/reference.html

> Avoiding parameter mapping
>
> If you want to prevent DbFit from mapping parameters to bind variables
>   (eg to execute a stored procedure definition that contains the @
>   symbol in Sql Server), disable bind symbols option before running the
>   query.
>
> |set option|bind symbols|false|
>
> |execute| insert into users (name, username) values ('@hey','uuu')|
>
> |query|select * from users| |name|username| |@hey|uuu|
>
> Remember to re-enable the option after the query is executed. You can
>   use the same trick with the Execute command.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mike's answer, you can also solve this by using bind parameters. This is useful if you have to use bind parameters at other places in the same query.

```
!|DatabaseEnvironment|ORACLE|
|Connect|${HOSTNAME}|${USERNAME}|${PASSWORD}|

!|Query|!-select current_timestamp ts from dual-!|
|ts?|
|>>my_birthday_ts|

|set parameter|my_birthday_ts| <<my_birthday_ts|
#Set bind parameter :MI to string ':MI'
|set parameter|MI|:MI|
# and do it in the same way with :SS.
|set parameter|SS|:SS|

!|Query|!-select to_char(:my_birthday_ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'|| :MI || :SS) bds from dual-!|
|bds?|
|>>birthday_string|
```

Note that you have to use !- -! around your query, otherwise FitNesse will expand the concatenation operator to table cells. The main drawback of this manner is that you cannot use ordinary FitNesse variables (${varname}) in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
!|DatabaseEnvironment|ORACLE|
|Connect|${HOSTNAME}|${USERNAME}|${PASSWORD}|

!|Query|!-select current_timestamp ts from dual-!|
|ts?|
|>>my_birthday_ts|


!|Query|!-select to_char(:my_birthday_ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:'||'MI:'||'SS) bds from dual-!|
|bds?|
|>>birthday_string|
```